# laravel model relationship 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

**1. users**
1. id
2. name

**2. categories**
1. id
2. category_name
3. user_id

**3. posts**
1. id
2. post_title
3. category_id

So now I want to show data in my view
like : post_title->category_name->user_name

How to do in laravel query relationship in model

Answer (score 1):

Define the relationships

```
class Post extends Model
{
    return $this->blongsTo(Category::class);
}

class Category extends Model
{
    return $this->blongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now

```
$post = with('category.user')->whereId(1)->first(); //1 is my guess

$post->category()->user->name();
```

Also it seems like a [has-many-through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship though you can access a user's post like this

```
$user->posts;
```

For that you need to define:

```
class User extends Model
{
/**
 * Get all of the posts for the user.
 */
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Post:class, Category::class);
}
}
```

Comment: @Md Majadul Islam check the answer

Comment: Very nice query @Mahdi Younesi but I would like to show my result   `$post = Post::with(............)->get->();  So now result is  post_title, category_name, user_name ?`

Comment: @Md Majadul Islam I edited the question, use `eager loading` $post->category->name ` or `$post->category->user->name`

Comment: randomId is default function in laravel ?

Comment: or you can find by slug or title `$post = with('category.user')->whereSlug('some-slug')->first(); `

Answer (score 0):

```
$Query=DB::select('select posts.post_title,categories.category_name,
users.name from posts,categories,users where users.id=categories.user_id and
categories.id=posts.category_id');
```

if you dont use DB::
you can use your model

```
$Query = Users::select('users.name', 'posts.post_title', 'categories.category_name')
        ->join('categories', function ($join) {
             $join->on('categories.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                  ->join('categories.id', '=', 'posts.category_id');
    })
        ->get();
```

check spell table name and columns 
but if there is duplicate in data it wont work

Comment: Thank you   @Ahmed Shams   but I dont use `DB`

Comment: why you just 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Comment: Actually I do not want to use DB because I will use modal relationships thats why i will not use